# Passing SQL query in url

Tags: sql, url

Client with 20,000 book database has a menu/submenu system of 75 pages. Each page, virtually identical, but with the relevant SQL query to load.

Is there a way to make each menu item carry the keywords in its URL link, needing only one page accepting the relevant search parameters from each menu URL?

Problem is how do I add the possible three keywords to look for (menu, sub and sub-submenu) into the URL. The first keyword works but can't get the AND or ampersand to work, nor the NOT EQUAL (<>)

http://www.wherever.com/search-results-keywords.php?keywords=Uniforms_and_keywords<>sold

Just by the way, it can't be this easy otherwise you could hack any database?

Comment: Have you considered the url could be modified by anyone, granting them full access to your database? You would be opening yourself to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Have a look at the [OData standard](http://www.odata.org/) - they've defined a way to do this quite nicely

Comment: I did wonder, Aaron, hence my last line. OData, thank you. Looks bit beyond me, Marc. So no nearer just writing a simple query in the syntax URLs required. I'll try more! Thanks.

Comment: @Jon not sure you do understand the implications of SQL injection here. you should never expose the capability to anyone of inserting SQL, even partly, unless you know exactly what you are doing ! Passing something like `1=1; Select * from users;` can be dramatic for your user security.

Answer (score 0):

When working with query string (`GET`), make sure you encode the query string properly

example:

```
var url = "http://www.website.com/search.php?" + encodeURIComponent(params);
```

`POST` is probably safer since you are using the parameter to query the database

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Odata](http://www.odata.org/getting-started/)

provide a restful style interact with you sql database.

compare with directly put SQL query into your URL, http://.../?sql="select * from  table where id = 'xxx'"

Odata can avoid sql injection, however you can't do everything sql can,

in another word, Odata has limit function, while sql can perform everything,

or you even can put stored procedure(a bunch of sql) into URL query string.

But you have to develop something to prevent sql injection.